# Using random numbers to select a item in one list and move it to another list

Tags: c#

I am designing a card game called Snap (Heres a link showing rules http://boardgames.about.com/od/cardgames/a/snap.htm), in my version, the player will have to click on the pile in the middle if a pair shows up. I have 4 classes currently, one for the card (which is a int called cardValue_), one for the players hand, one for the original deck of cards and one for the pile of cards in the middle. So the Deck, Pile and Hand classes has a List of Cards in them. I am now trying to write a shuffle method for the Deck class which contains a list of Cards. Which will pick a random card and move it to a new list until all the cards are picked, then move them back to the original list, thus doing a simple shuffle. My method so far looks like this...

```
public List<Deck> Shuffle(List<Card> cardDeck)
    {
        int index = 0;
        Random randomCard = new Random();
        List<Card> newDeck = new List<Card>();

        while (index < cardDeck.Count)
        {
            int ran = randomCard.Next(0, cardDeck.Count);
            foreach (Card card in cardDeck)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to work out what should go in the foreach loop (unless the whole method is wrong), but now I am thinking I have declared all my Cards in the wrong place, all 52 cards are currently declared in the Form, or should i be declaring them in the Deck class?

Comment: I can't improve on Jeff's blog on http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where fairly close to how I would solve it, what I would do is copy out of the source list randomly until it is empty and then just refill it. You don't need to return a list as this will just shuffle the list you pass in.

```
//Move this out of the function, if you are wondering why search SO for "Not random" and choose any of the 100's of people asking "why is random not random?" :)
private static Random randomCard = new Random(); //Not thread safe, if multi-threading use locks!!!

public static void Shuffle(List<Card> cardDeck)
{
    int index = 0;
    List<Card> tempDeck = new List<Card>();

    while (cardDeck.Count > 0)
    {
        int removal = randomCard.Next(0, cardDeck.Count);
        Card tempCard = cardDeck[removal];
        cardDeck.RemoveAt(removal);
        tempDeck.Add(tempCard);
    }

    //cardDeck is empty at this point, now we refill it with our randomized deck.
    cardDeck.AddRange(tempDeck);
}
```

---

If you want to not modify the original list and you do want a new randomized list just copy the source list first.

```
public static List<Card> Shuffle(List<Card> cardDeck)
{
    int index = 0;
    List<Card> tempDeck = new List<Card>();
    List<Card> localCopy = new List<Card>(cardDeck);   //Creates a shallow copy of the list.      

    while (localCopy.Count > 0)
    {
        int removal = randomCard.Next(0, cardDeck.Count);
        Card tempCard = localCopy[removal];
        localCopy.RemoveAt(removal);
        tempDeck.Add(tempCard);
    }

    return tempDeck;
}
```

---

I would recommend using [Richard's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14766143/80274). it is much simpler.

Comment: This type of shuffle can be predicted.  Read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html

Comment: @RichardSchneider Hmm, thanks for the read. I did not think of the order by trick. Post that as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @RichardSchneider However, I would say that calling `NewGuid()` is just as predictable as calling `Next(x,y)`. If you are truly wanting to do it "right" you need to crack open `System.Security.Cryptography`

Comment: Hmm, for some reason in both your examples. Where it says Card tempCard...; i get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Snap_Card_Game.Card" (Snap Card Game is the name of the solution)

Comment: Sorry to bother you with a trivial question, since this method is in a class, does that mean it automatically executes when I create a deckList or do I still have to call the method somewhere? This is the first time I have used multiple classes.

Comment: You would need to call it, in fact the  function **should** be static (I updated my code). It would be called like `Deck.Shuffle(someListOfCards)` (if `Deck` is the name of the class the function `Shuffle` is inside of)

Comment: But now that means i need to move the declaration of the random variable into the method, which will now mean its not as random anymore. Its fine, I don't need it to be perfectly random, any amount of randomness is better than none.

Comment: You can make `Random` static too, as long as you call it only from one thread at a time, or if you will be using multi-threading be sure to use `lock` correctly to access it. If you need help understanding locks feel free to open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Read Jeff's [blog on shuffling](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html) for all the details.

```
public List<Card> Shuffle(List<Card> cards)
{
  return new List<Card>(cards)
   .OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid());
}
```

**Update**

Scott suggested that a Guid may not be random enough and Crypto RNG would be better.  So using BigInteger because it implements IComparable we get:

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

public List<Card> Shuffle(List<Card> cards)
{
  var r = new byte[32];
  return new List<Card>(cards)
   .OrderBy(a => new BigInteger(rng.GetBytes(r));
}
```

Comment: it's just wrong to use uniqueness where you really want randomness - different use cases