# Making sure the same list output doesn't come up twice

Tags: c#

I am making a sort of self-quizzer where you add questions to then quiz yourself.

I want to be able to get all the questions to you (randomized if possible).
I already have it somewhat working but it occasionally misses some questions or repeats them.

```
public void LoadUp() {
    if(TimeLimit) {
        timer2.Start();
    }

    KeyWords.Clear();
    Hint_Used=false;
    int QuestionCount=correct+incorrect;
    int AnswerCount=Study_Helper.Form1.QuizList.Count;
    Random random=new Random();
    int randomNumber=random.Next(0, Study_Helper.Form1.QuizList.Count);

    if(!Study_Helper.Form1.PreviousQuestions.Contains(randomNumber)) {
        Study_Helper.Form1.PreviousQuestions.Add(randomNumber);
        String raw=Study_Helper.Form1.QuizList[randomNumber].ToString();
        String[] Split=raw.Split(new char[] { '|' });
        Question=Split[0];
        richTextBox1.Text=Question;
        Answer=Split[1];
        Hint=Split[2];
        String[] NewSplit=Split[3].Split(new char[] { ',' });
        int TotalKeywords=0;

        foreach(string s in NewSplit) {
            TotalKeywords++;
        }

        for(int size=0; size<TotalKeywords-1; size++) {
            String KeyWord=NewSplit[size].ToString();
            KeyWords.Add(KeyWord);
        }
    }
    else if(QuestionCount>=AnswerCount) {
        int Total=correct-incorrect;

        if(Total<0) {
            Total=0;
        }

        timer2.Stop();
        Counter=Study_Helper.Form4.Counter;
        Form6 form6=new Form6();
        form6.Show();
        TimeLimit=false;
        MessageBox.Show("Study Questions over! you got "+Total+" in total, that's "+correct+" correct answers!", "Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        correct=0;
        incorrect=0;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

What it does is add the random number to a list that hold it, and checks if already contains it. I feel that I am missing something obvious to make this work fluently.

Comment: Please edit the code snippet and leave only *meaningful* part of it.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `PreviousQuestions` to track all the indices is complicate yourself. I'd suggest to shuffle the indices at the beginning so once you have a stack initialized with this method, you have only to call `randomNumbers.Pop()` to get a new random number.

```
Stack<int> ShuffleNumbers(int count)
{
    IEnumerable<int> range = Enumerable.Range(0, count);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return new Stack<int>(range.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is is to randomize the list then start processing it in order.

```
var randomizedList = Study_Helper.Form1.QuizList.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid());

foreach(var question in randomizedList)
{
    //Handle displaying the question.
}
```

What this is doing is "Sorting" the list, however because we are giving the sorter a new random<sup>1</sup> `Guid` every time so it will randomize the list. We then can use this scrambled quiz for the rest of the code.

<sup>1. This is not a "safe" way to do random as someone could do cryptanalysis on the output to predict the order of the questions, but you are not trying to be cryptographically secure, you are just trying to scramble quiz questions and this solution is good enough for that. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765845/using-random-numbers-to-select-a-item-in-one-list-and-move-it-to-another-list/14765967#14765967) on shuffling a deck of cards for more info.</sup>